# SQL Server is lagging despite using only 10GB RAM out of 80GB

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, memory, connection-timeout

I have a server that is hosting 3 Web apps:
web app A is not used frequently.
web app B is use daily with total 13-14 users. This web app will access SQL Server for create, read, update, delete query.
web app C is a folder browser. Web app B will add files in web app C.

Regarding the server spec:
[Server Spec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPbi8.png)

The SQL server seems to be accumulating memory. In 1 week, the memory can exceeds to 10GB of RAM usage, and started to get lagging, having SQLException timeout error.
[SQL Server memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXSXp.png)

I thought 80GB of RAM would be enough and SQL server will just use the resources given that I did not change the Max memory value.
[SQL Server memory default setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/im6f1.png)

Web app B is a custom made where the query to SQL Server is attached:

```
internal List<object> GetDbDataSqlConnection(string commandText, Dictionary<string, object> kvp, string columns, string company = null)
        {
            List<object> dataList = new List<object>();

            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection($"data source={WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sqldatasource"]};initial catalog={company ?? WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["defaultsqldb"]};user id={WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sqlusername"]};password={WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sqlpassword"]};MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand { CommandText = commandText, CommandType = CommandType.Text, Connection = sqlConnection })
                    {
                        if (kvp != null) foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> p in kvp) cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@{p.Key.Replace(".", string.Empty)}", p.Value);

                        sqlConnection.Open();

                        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                Dictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                                foreach (string c in columns.Split(','))
                                {
                                    string x = c.Contains(" AS ") ? c.Substring(c.IndexOf(" AS ") + 4) : c;
                                    x = x.Replace("[", string.Empty).Replace("]", string.Empty);
                                    x = x.Substring(x.IndexOf(".") + 1);
                                    data.Add(x, Convert.ToString(reader[x]).Trim());
                                }
                                dataList.Add(data);
                            }

                            reader.Close();
                        }

                        sqlConnection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.WriteLog($"[ERROR] on GetDbDataSqlConnection");
                Logger.WriteLog($"Exception message : {ex.Message}");
                Logger.WriteLog($"Exception : {ex}");
                throw ex;
            }

            return dataList;
        }
```

My question is, is there anything that I need to do to improve the code or the SQL Server configuration to prevent this from happening again?

thank you.

I had to restart SQL service then the web app B become smooth again.

Edit 1:
I am attaching the result from query
[Wait Stat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/So1kL.png)

Edit 2:
The Web App B do a lot of things.

1. select data directly from SQL
   Mobile app send GET request to Web app B.
   Then web app B do SQL select query, and response back to mobile app.
2. do API request to a web API
   Mobile app send POST Request to Web app B.
   Web app B do validation, that consist of SQL select query, and send a POST request to a Web API. The web API is also hosted on the same server. The Web App B response back to mobile app.

Edit 3: Error message

```
Exception : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at SalesMaster.Business.DataGeneral.DatabaseDataProcess.GetDbDataSqlConnection(String commandText, Dictionary`2 kvp, String columns, String company)
```

Edit 4: these are some of the query that is used.

```
[13-03-2024T08:42:19]    Command Text=SELECT C.IDCUST,C.NAMECUST,C.PRICLIST,C.TEXTPHON1 
FROM JDCUSGRP CG INNER JOIN ARCUS C ON CG.IDCUST = C.IDCUST 
WHERE CODESLSP=@CODESLSP AND SWACTV=@SWACTV 
ORDER BY C.IDCUST;
[13-03-2024T08:42:22]    Command Text=SELECT DISTINCT T.ITEMNO, T.FMTITEMNO, T.[DESC], T.DEFPRICLST, T.TQUANTITY - T.FQUANTITY + T.AQUANTITY - T.OQUANTITY + T.CQUANTITY + T.XQUANTITY AS STOCK 
FROM(
    SELECT I.ITEMNO, I.FMTITEMNO, I.[DESC], I.DEFPRICLST, 
    CASE WHEN FTF.QUANTITY IS NOT NULL THEN FTF.QUANTITY ELSE 0 END AS FQUANTITY, 
    CASE WHEN TTF.QUANTITY IS NOT NULL THEN TTF.QUANTITY ELSE 0 END AS TQUANTITY, 
    CASE WHEN AD.QUANTITY IS NOT NULL THEN AD.QUANTITY ELSE 0 END AS AQUANTITY, 
    CASE WHEN ORD.QUANTITY IS NOT NULL THEN ORD.QUANTITY ELSE 0 END AS OQUANTITY, 
    CASE WHEN CRD.QUANTITY IS NOT NULL THEN CRD.QUANTITY ELSE 0 END AS CQUANTITY, 
    CASE WHEN XCH.QUANTITY IS NOT NULL THEN XCH.QUANTITY ELSE 0 END AS XQUANTITY 
    FROM JDITMGRP IG 
    INNER JOIN ICITEM I ON IG.ITEMNO = I.ITEMNO 
    LEFT JOIN ICLOC L ON IG.CODESLSP = L.[DESC] 
    OUTER APPLY(SELECT DISTINCT SUM(D.QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY 
                FROM ICTRED D 
                INNER JOIN ICTREH H ON D.TRANFENSEQ = H.TRANFENSEQ 
                WHERE D.ITEMNO = I.FMTITEMNO AND D.FROMLOC = L.LOCATION AND H.TRANSDATE = @Transdate AND H.DOCTYPE = 1 
                GROUP BY D.ITEMNO) FTF 
    OUTER APPLY(SELECT DISTINCT SUM(D.QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY 
                FROM ICTRED D INNER JOIN ICTREH H ON D.TRANFENSEQ = H.TRANFENSEQ 
                WHERE D.ITEMNO = I.FMTITEMNO AND D.TOLOC = L.LOCATION AND H.TRANSDATE = @Transdate AND H.DOCTYPE = 1 
                GROUP BY D.ITEMNO) TTF 
    OUTER APPLY(SELECT DISTINCT SUM(D.QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY 
                FROM ICADEH H 
                INNER JOIN ICADED D ON H.ADJENSEQ = D.ADJENSEQ 
                WHERE D.ITEMNO = I.FMTITEMNO AND H.REFERENCE = L.LOCATION AND H.TRANSDATE = @Transdate 
                GROUP BY D.ITEMNO) AD 
    OUTER APPLY(SELECT DISTINCT SUM(D.ORIGQTY) AS QUANTITY 
                FROM OEORDH H 
                INNER JOIN OEORDD D ON H.ORDUNIQ = D.ORDUNIQ 
                WHERE D.ITEM = I.FMTITEMNO AND H.LOCATION = L.LOCATION AND H.ORDDATE = @Transdate 
                GROUP BY D.ITEM) ORD 
    OUTER APPLY(SELECT DISTINCT SUM(D.QTYRETURN) AS QUANTITY 
                FROM OECRDH H 
                INNER JOIN OECRDD D ON H.CRDUNIQ = D.CRDUNIQ 
                WHERE D.ITEM = I.FMTITEMNO AND H.LOCATION = L.LOCATION AND H.CRDDATE = @Transdate 
                GROUP BY D.ITEM) CRD 
    OUTER APPLY(SELECT DISTINCT SUM(X.XCHGQTY) AS QUANTITY 
                FROM JDXCHGRT X WHERE X.ITEMNO = I.ITEMNO AND X.CODESLSP = IG.CODESLSP AND XCHGDATE = @Transdate 
                GROUP BY X.ITEMNO) XCH 
                WHERE IG.CODESLSP = @Codeslsp) T 
                ORDER BY T.ITEMNO;
[13-03-2024T08:42:23]    Command Text=SELECT DISTINCT T.*, CASE WHEN P2.SALESTART <> 0 AND P2.SALEEND <> 0 THEN P2.UNITPRICE ELSE P1.UNITPRICE END AS UNITPRICE
FROM (
    SELECT CURRENCY, ITEMNO, PRICELIST FROM ICPRICP
    WHERE PRICELIST IN(
        SELECT DISTINCT C.PRICLIST AS PRICLIST FROM JDCUSGRP CG INNER JOIN ARCUS C ON CG.IDCUST = C.IDCUST WHERE CG.CODESLSP = 'S1'
        UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT I.DEFPRICLST AS PRICLIST FROM JDITMGRP IG INNER JOIN ICITEM I ON IG.ITEMNO = I.ITEMNO WHERE IG.CODESLSP = 'S1'
    ) AND ITEMNO IN (SELECT ITEMNO FROM JDITMGRP WHERE CODESLSP = 'S1')
) T
LEFT JOIN ICPRICP P1 ON T.CURRENCY = P1.CURRENCY AND T.ITEMNO = P1.ITEMNO AND T.PRICELIST = P1.PRICELIST AND P1.DPRICETYPE = 1
LEFT JOIN ICPRICP P2 ON T.CURRENCY = P2.CURRENCY AND T.ITEMNO = P2.ITEMNO AND T.PRICELIST = P2.PRICELIST AND P2.DPRICETYPE = 2
;
[13-03-2024T08:43:06]    Command Text=SELECT BANK,NAME FROM BKACCT  ORDER BY BANK;
[13-03-2024T08:43:06]    Command Text=SELECT LOCATION,[DESC] FROM ICLOC  ORDER BY [DESC];
[13-03-2024T08:44:32]    Command Text=SELECT H.REFERENCE,H.INVNUMBER,H.CUSTOMER,C.NAMECUST,C.PRICLIST,C.TEXTPHON1 
FROM OEINVH H 
INNER JOIN ARCUS C ON H.CUSTOMER = C.IDCUST 
WHERE H.INVDATE=@HINVDATE AND H.SALESPER1=@HSALESPER1 
GROUP BY H.REFERENCE,H.INVNUMBER,H.CUSTOMER,C.NAMECUST,C.PRICLIST,C.TEXTPHON1 
ORDER BY H.REFERENCE;
[13-03-2024T08:44:40]    Command Text=SELECT H.INVNUMBER,H.REFERENCE,B.IDBANK,R.TXTRMITREF,R.IDRMIT,H.CUSTOMER,C.NAMECUST,
CASE WHEN R.CODEPAYM IS NULL THEN CASE WHEN C.CODETERM = 'CASH' THEN 'UNPAID' ELSE 'CREDIT' END ELSE R.CODEPAYM END AS PAYTYPE,
CASE WHEN P.AMTPAYM IS NULL THEN H.INVNETWTX ELSE P.AMTPAYM END AS AMOUNT,H.INVDISCAMT,I.ITEMNO,D.ITEM,D.[DESC],D.QTYORDERED,D.UNITPRICE 
FROM OEINVH H 
INNER JOIN OEINVD D ON H.INVUNIQ = D.INVUNIQ 
LEFT JOIN ARTCP P ON H.INVNUMBER = P.IDINVC 
LEFT JOIN ARTCR R ON P.CNTBTCH = R.CNTBTCH AND P.CNTITEM = R.CNTITEM 
LEFT JOIN ARBTA B ON R.CNTBTCH = B.CNTBTCH 
INNER JOIN ARCUS C ON H.CUSTOMER = C.IDCUST 
INNER JOIN ICITEM I ON D.ITEM = I.FMTITEMNO 
WHERE H.INVDATE=@HINVDATE AND H.SALESPER1=@HSALESPER1  ;
[13-03-2024T08:44:59]    Command Text=SELECT DISTINCT IG.ITEMNO, I.FMTITEMNO, I.[DESC], ISNULL(TFT.QUANTITY, 0) - ISNULL(TFF.QUANTITY, 0) + ISNULL(AD.QUANTITY, 0) AS STOCK, ISNULL(ORD.QUANTITY, 0) AS SALE, ISNULL(CRD.QUANTITY, 0) AS CREDIT, ISNULL(XCH.QUANTITY, 0) AS EXCHANGE 
FROM JDITMGRP IG 
INNER JOIN ICITEM I ON IG.ITEMNO = I.ITEMNO 
LEFT JOIN ICLOC L ON IG.CODESLSP = L.[DESC] 
OUTER APPLY(SELECT DISTINCT SUM(D.QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY 
            FROM ICTRED D 
            INNER JOIN ICTREH H ON D.TRANFENSEQ = H.TRANFENSEQ 
            WHERE D.ITEMNO = I.FMTITEMNO AND D.TOLOC = L.LOCATION AND H.TRANSDATE = @Transdate AND H.DOCTYPE = 1 GROUP BY D.ITEMNO) TFT 
OUTER APPLY(SELECT DISTINCT SUM(D.QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY FROM ICTRED D 
            INNER JOIN ICTREH H ON D.TRANFENSEQ = H.TRANFENSEQ 
            WHERE D.ITEMNO = I.FMTITEMNO AND D.FROMLOC = L.LOCATION AND H.TRANSDATE = @Transdate AND H.DOCTYPE = 1 
            GROUP BY D.ITEMNO) TFF 
OUTER APPLY(SELECT DISTINCT SUM(D.QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY 
            FROM ICADED D 
            INNER JOIN ICADEH H ON D.ADJENSEQ = H.ADJENSEQ 
            WHERE D.ITEMNO = I.FMTITEMNO AND H.REFERENCE = L.LOCATION AND H.TRANSDATE = @Transdate 
            GROUP BY D.ITEMNO) AD 
OUTER APPLY(SELECT DISTINCT SUM(D.ORIGQTY) AS QUANTITY 
            FROM OEORDH H 
            INNER JOIN OEORDD D ON H.ORDUNIQ = D.ORDUNIQ 
            WHERE D.ITEM = I.FMTITEMNO AND H.LOCATION = L.LOCATION AND H.ORDDATE = @Transdate 
            GROUP BY D.ITEM) ORD 
OUTER APPLY(SELECT DISTINCT SUM(D.QTYRETURN) AS QUANTITY 
            FROM OECRDH H 
            INNER JOIN OECRDD D ON H.CRDUNIQ = D.CRDUNIQ 
            WHERE D.ITEM = I.FMTITEMNO AND H.LOCATION = L.LOCATION AND H.CRDDATE = @Transdate 
            GROUP BY D.ITEM) CRD 
OUTER APPLY(SELECT DISTINCT SUM(X.XCHGQTY) AS QUANTITY 
            FROM JDXCHGRT X WHERE X.ITEMNO = I.ITEMNO AND X.CODESLSP = IG.CODESLSP AND X.XCHGDATE = @Transdate 
            GROUP BY X.ITEMNO) XCH 
WHERE IG.CODESLSP=@IGCODESLSP ;
[13-03-2024T08:44:59]    Command Text=SELECT DISTINCT I.ITEMNO, D.ITEM, D.[DESC], D.UNITPRICE, D.QTYORDERED, 
STRING_AGG(TRIM(COALESCE(R.CODEPAYM, CASE WHEN C.CODETERM = 'CASH' THEN 'UNPAID' ELSE 'CREDIT' END)), ' & ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TRIM(COALESCE(R.CODEPAYM, CASE WHEN C.CODETERM = 'CASH' THEN 'UNPAID' ELSE 'CREDIT' END))) AS PAYTYPE 
FROM OEINVH H 
INNER JOIN OEINVD D ON H.INVUNIQ = D.INVUNIQ 
INNER JOIN ICITEM I ON D.ITEM = I.FMTITEMNO 
LEFT JOIN ARTCP P ON H.INVNUMBER = P.IDINVC 
LEFT JOIN ARTCR R ON P.CNTBTCH = R.CNTBTCH AND P.CNTITEM = R.CNTITEM 
INNER JOIN ARCUS C ON H.CUSTOMER = C.IDCUST 
WHERE H.SALESPER1=@HSALESPER1 AND H.INVDATE=@HINVDATE 
GROUP BY H.INVNUMBER, I.ITEMNO, D.ITEM, D.[DESC], D.UNITPRICE, D.QTYORDERED ;
[13-03-2024T08:45:10]    Command Text=SELECT SUM(R.AMTRMITTC) AS CASHONHAND 
FROM ARTCR R 
INNER JOIN ARTCP P ON R.CNTBTCH = P.CNTBTCH AND R.CNTITEM = P.CNTITEM 
INNER JOIN AROBL D ON P.IDINVC = D.IDINVC 
WHERE R.DATERMIT=@RDATERMIT AND R.CODEPAYM=@RCODEPAYM AND D.CODESLSP1=@DCODESLSP1  ;
[13-03-2024T08:46:42]    Command Text=SELECT CONAME,ADDR01,ADDR02,ADDR03,PHONE,HOMECUR FROM CSCOM WHERE ORGID=@ORGID ;
```

Comment: I guess this is some kind of "generic" query executor ? Why don't you use Dapper for example ?

Comment: Please attach the result of thiis query to your question: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/

Comment: @sepupic I have edit the question to add the result from the wait stat query

Comment: We can't guess what your query does, what the execution plan is, or whether there are missing indexes or worse, the query prevents the use of indexes. The code in the question is certainly unconventional and unnecessary

Comment: The wait stats don't help. They don't show what the actual query is or what it's doing. The high network IO may mean you're trying to return a lot of data to the client over a slow network, which is still a *coding* problem, not a SQL Server problem. Why return so much data in the first place? Once again, what is the query doing?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the code is just executing SQL statement such as "Select columns from tables where column=x". I think that is the normal way to do it. But my knowledge is only up to that. What is more conventional way to execute a SQL statement?

Comment: The slow dictionary code may be causing the delays if it's repeated over a lot of data too  . It's calculating the same static column names over and over, and then generating a *lot* of temporary strings. That means generating dozens of temporary strings for every row for no reason. If you repeat this for several thousand rows, at some point the garbage collector will kick in and try to clean them up, freezing the client

Comment: @MurniYanti there's nothing "just" in this code, and the *query* is the most important thing. `WHERE Column=x` over an unindexed column and 1M rows will cause a scan of all 1M rows, using a lot of data and CPU. If each row is close to the maximum, you're flooding the network which could account for the Network waits

Comment: @Murni Yanti There is no RAM problem at all your problem is the slow client that consumes the result in too long time. ASYNC_NETWORK_IO indicates this.

Comment: It can be slow network or too big result sets that the client consumes slowly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in the Edit 3, I add the error message. the error is related to SQLExecuteReader, not dictionary.

Comment: LCK_M_S tells you that you have a small percentage of locking when reading the data that is modifying so I recommend you also to enable RCSI (Read Committed Snapshot Isolation) on youe database so the readers will no more wait for the writers and read the last committed version

Comment: Post the query and execution plan. Nothing else matters. You got a timeout because the query took too long. We can't guess what the query is doing. We have a tiny hint that it's returning more data that the client or network can handle but *nothing else*

Comment: There is so much wrong here it's hard to know where to start. The column generation certainly should be factored out. The dictionary should be pre-sized to the right number of columns. `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` doesn't make sense here. And yes you should probably just use a proper ORM like EF Core or Dapper. Whatever the `WHERE` clause is doing, if it's not indexed properly it's going to be slow. It's normal for memory usage to go up, my SQL Server is using 100GB and it's *supposed* to do that.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have added the query in edit 4. I admit the query is too long.

Comment: Based on the suggestion here, I will try on using ORM like Dapper or EF Core, and simplify the query where possible

Comment: The problem is the query, not Dapper or EF. That's a prohibitively slow query no matter the server. Every subquery called with `OUTER APPLY` executes as a separate query and gets cached so it can be used in the rest of the query. The fact you need to use `DISTINT SUM()` means the subqueries have issues too. That's not a server issue, that's an issue of this SQL code and the table design. The fact you had to write such a query though means the tables aren't appropriate for this business scenario.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run a reporting query over an OLTP (transactional) database. That's fundamentally wrong. You can get several orders of magnitude better performance (as in 1000 and more) if you use a separate reporting database, perhaps using a [star schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I cannot do anything to the table design because the table is from an ERP system and I am just querying from it. But I will do something on the sql statement

Comment: Which means you SHOULDN'T query from it. You should export the data to a reporting database or data warehouse. I'd bet the ERP already has such a database - all ERPs include reporting. What you do now isn't just slow, it slows down the users of the ERP.